# avoiding negative predictions in MLPRegressor in scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

Though I have used `StandardScaler` or `MinMaxScaler` to preprocess my data while solving problem with `MLPRegressor` in `sklearn`, the predicted values have lot of negative numbers though the training set has all real positive values. Data is here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JF_EpyiMF5WzKZOt6d0iA2174eAheaTW.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y)

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = min_max_scaler.transform(x_test)

mlp = MLPRegressor(activation='logistic' , solver='sgd' ,verbose=10, hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10), max_iter=1000)
mlp.fit(x_train, y_train)

print("Training set score :%f" % mlp.score(x_train, y_train))
print("Test score :%f" % mlp.score(x_test, y_test))

predictions = mlp.predict(x_test)
```

Any suggestion where is the problem?

Comment: Have you reversed the scaling? i.e. `predictions = min_max_scaler.inverse_transform(mlp.predict(x_test) )`

Comment: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (63,60) (15,) (63,60) ..  : This is the error showing for inverse transform. @ncfirth

Comment: Yeah that's fair that was a really silly thing of me to suggest, I misunderstood and thought you had scaled the output. Sorry!

Comment: Another point. I have used MATLAB levenberg marquardt algorithm and got very promising result. Is there any equivalent algorithm in sklearn ? @ncfirth